# Is "solar insolation" a tautology?

Tags: meaning

I'm not a native English speaker and I found "insolation" to translate into something like "solar irradiation", i.e. the qualifier "solar" already seems to be inherent to "insolation". Still, I often see "insolation" preceded by "solar". Is this a tautology?

Comment: Yes. It's a tautology. Sometimes people prefix a word with an adjective in the misguided belief that it will help people who don't know the word.

Comment: There's no harm in a little tautology - the goal of language is to express a meaning in the clearest way, not in the fewest letters. It does appear tautologous, certainly compared to equivalent phrases like "solar irradiation" which is definitely not tautologous, but if you're not sure what insolation means then it's a help. Although using a more common word would also help. As to whether it's helpful or unnecessary, that's harder to answer - it depends on your audience.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally agree with what both of you said. Sorry if my question came across as pedantic. I was just curious.

Comment: I think it's a tautology, and I don't like it. The writer could avoid the less common word *insolation*, but since it's been introduced, let it stand on its own. If you are afraid that your readers won't know what it means, put in a parenthetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is tautological. *Insolation*, per [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CAJIKU_enUS1045&q=insolation), is a technical term that refers to

> a. exposure to the sun's rays.
> b. the amount of solar radiation reaching a given area.

And *solar*, as you probably know, can mean 'of, related to, or determined by the sun.'

So, yes, that *solar* is unnecessary, but on the other hand, it's also part of a very common construction- [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solar%20insolation%22&biw=1366&bih=665&tbm=bks&ei=wKs9ZIDDL8OjptQPtp6ZgAk&ved=0ahUKEwiAo_mv4LH-AhXDkYkEHTZPBpA46gMQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22solar%20insolation%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwJQAFgAYK4DaABwAHgAgAGpAogBqQKSAQMyLTGYAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books&safe=active&ssui=on) gives almost 50 pages of results for "solar insolation," and, besides, who does it hurt? Though tautologies are often maligned, they are not necessarily incorrect, sometimes help make things clearer, and are *really* useful when you're struggling to hit a word count :)

So ultimately, it's a question of style and what you prefer.